# My code doesn't run the same way on different compilers

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, compiler-errors

first of all, I'm just starting to learn C programming on my own so please don't be mad if I'm explaining or doing something wrong, I tried to search similar question to my problem on StackOverflow but I couldn’t find one so please if I'm doing something wrong, take it easy on me I'm only trying to learn.

I have an issue I can't understand, I wrote a sorting list program using the Insertion sort algorithm, that runs differently on different compilers.
when I enter only positive numbers everything works smoothly but if I add some negatives numbers, depending on the compiler, it sometimes works and sometimes does not work at all/ prints a weird result

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

  // gathering sources for sorting an array:
  int myArray[5];
  int count = 1;
  for (int arrayIndex = 0; arrayIndex < 5; arrayIndex++)
  {
  
    printf("\nEnter the #%d array element: ", count);
    scanf(" %d", &myArray[arrayIndex]);
    count++;
  }

  // calculate the last array index 
  int myInt = myArray[0];
  int arrayLength = ((sizeof(myArray)) / (sizeof(myInt))) - 1;

  // printing the unsorted array
  printf("\nthe array was: ");
  for (int i = 0; i <= arrayLength; i++)
  {
    printf(" %d ", myArray[i]);
  }
 
 // sorting the array using insertion sorting algorithm:

  for (int index = 1; index <= arrayLength; index++)
  {
    int numberCheck = index;
    while (index >= 1 && myArray[numberCheck] < myArray[numberCheck - 1])
    {
      // swap the places:

      int temp;
      temp = myArray[numberCheck];
      myArray[numberCheck] = myArray[numberCheck - 1];
      myArray[numberCheck - 1] = temp;

      // move the next element
      numberCheck--;
    }
  }
  // printing the sorted array:
  
  printf("\nthe sorted array is now: ");
  for (int i = 0; i <= arrayLength; i++)
  {
    printf(" %d ", myArray[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

for example if I enter (0,-2,-4,12,5)
on *C Online Compiler - Programiz*
I get this result :

```
the array was:  0  -2  -4  12  5 
the sorted array is now:  -4  -2  0  5  12
```

but if I enter the same exact code on the Vscode Zsh compiler (I'm using a MacBook and to my knowledge, I didn't change anything on the compiler settings)
I get the result :

```
the array was:  0  -2  -4  12  5 
the sorted array is now:  5  6
```

Comment: The code gives me 2 compilation errors so it can't be run. Have a look at this incomplete line `myArray[numberCheck] = myArray[numberCheck - `. Best to copy-paste the whole code in one hit.

Comment: Aside: to decrement `arrayLength` and then iterate with `for (int i = 0; i <= arrayLength; i++)` is not idiomatic.

Comment: The program has undefined behavior. Compile with `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` and then run the program to see problems you need to fix. `myArray[numberCheck - 1]` when `numberCheck` is `0` is one cause.

Comment: I see a loop that decrements `numberCheck` on each iteration, but I don't see anything that prevents `myArray[numberCheck-1]` from accessing a value beyond the start of `myArray`.

Comment: zsh is not a C compiler, never use online compilers to validate your program, they have newbie settings, gcc or clang or mvc or ... are your friend

Comment: Ofri K, `((sizeof(myArray)) / (sizeof(myInt)))` is wrong when `sizeof int != sizeof myInt`.  Use `(sizeof myArray / sizeof myArray[0])`.

Comment: okay thanks a lot! I swapped the numberCheck with index so I prevented  "myArray[numberCheck-1]" to reach a value beyond the start of "myArray" and it fixed the problem, thank you a lot for the help!

Comment: @rioV8 *"they have newbie settings"* what "expert" settings do you need? Enlight me, please.

Comment: Please don't do things like this `int arrayLength = sizeof(...)/sizeof(...) -1` and then `for (int i = 0; i <= arrayLength; i++)`. It is confusing. No one writes code like that. The length is NOT the index of the last element. The length is the number of elements. You rarely need the index of the last elements, and when you do, just write `arrayLength-1`. Please always, and I do mean always, write `arrayLength = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);` and then your loops should be `for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)` (note `<` not `<=`). That's how we work in C.

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. Thank you very much for your comment, it’s really helpful  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested out your code and found a few areas where processing of array elements was going out of bounds.  Some places, the value of the index was -1 and some places the value was equal to the array length value (e.g. index values that equate to myArray[5] which again is out of bounds).

Following is a copy of your code with a bit of cleanup to illustrate some usual and customary methods for processing "for" loops and processing arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    // gathering sources for sorting an array:
    int myArray[5];
    int count = 1;
    for (int arrayIndex = 0; arrayIndex < 5; arrayIndex++)
    {

        printf("\nEnter the #%d array element: ", count);
        scanf(" %d", &myArray[arrayIndex]);
        count++;
    }

    // calculate the last array index
    int myInt = myArray[0];
    int arrayLength = ((sizeof(myArray)) / (sizeof(myInt)));  /* Omittted the subtraction of 1 */

    // printing the unsorted array
    printf("\nthe array was: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)                     /* Set loop test to be less than array length */
    {
        printf(" %d ", myArray[i]);
    }

// sorting the array using insertion sorting algorithm:

    for (int index = 1; index < arrayLength; index++)
    {
        int numberCheck = index;
        //while (index >= 1 && myArray[numberCheck] < myArray[numberCheck - 1])     /* This line of code was allowing numberCheck - 1 to be less than zero */
        while (numberCheck > 0 && myArray[numberCheck] < myArray[numberCheck - 1])  /* Revised version of the test */
        {
            // swap the places:
            int temp;
            temp = myArray[numberCheck];
            myArray[numberCheck] = myArray[numberCheck - 1];
            myArray[numberCheck - 1] = temp;

            // move the next element
            numberCheck--;
        }
    }
    // printing the sorted array:

    printf("\nthe sorted array is now: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)       /* Revised this to not go out of bounds */
    {
        printf(" %d ", myArray[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

It appears in the program that you are attempting set up for loop and range testing based on a range of "1" to "array length"; whereas, the usual range processing is from "0" to "less than array length".  When I did those bits of cleanup, I was able to acquire a properly sorted array from the five values entered.

```
@Una:~/C_Programs/Console/Sorting/bin/Release$ ./Sorting 

Enter the #1 array element: 700

Enter the #2 array element: 343

Enter the #3 array element: 2

Enter the #4 array element: 58

Enter the #5 array element: 400
Array length: 5

the array was:  700  343  2  58  400 
the sorted array is now:  2  58  343  400  700
```

Note the comments I added to hopefully clarify bits for you.  Try that out and see if it meets the spirit of your project.